# adjoint representation of $sp(4,\mathbb{R})$.

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I want to show that the adjoint representation of $sp(4,\mathbb{R})$ is irreducible, but I am kind of stuck.

I can assume there's some non zero subspace of $sp(4,\mathbb{R})$ which is invariant under $ad_X$, where $X \in sp(4,\mathbb{R})$, but I don't see how to show that they are equal?

Any hints?

Comment: $sp(4)$ is a simple Lie algebra ($B_2$ in the classification); that's equivalent to irreducibility of the adjoint representation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are few more details for the answer given in the comment by user8268:

Let ${\mathfrak g}$ be a (finite-dimensional) Lie algebra with the Lie group $G$. Irreducibility of the adjoint action of $G$ would follow from irreducibility of the adjoint action of the Lie algebra ${\mathfrak g}$ on itself. The latter means that there are no proper subspaces $V\subset {\mathfrak g}$ so that $[v,g]\in V$ for all $v\in V, g\in {\mathfrak g}$. Such a subspace would necessarily be an *ideal* in ${\mathfrak g}$. A Lie algebra ${\mathfrak g}$ is called *simple* if it has no proper ideals. Proof of simplicity of the Lie algebra ${\mathfrak g}=sp(4)$ can be found in any book on Lie algebras.

Comment: Can you recommend me to a good reference where the simplicity of $sp(4)$ is covered? Thanks.

Comment: @MathematicalPhysicist: I do not know if this is a good reference or not, but the detailed calculation of Killing forms and root systems for all classical Lie algebras can be found in Holgason's book "Differential geometry lie groups and symmetric spaces", section III.3. Once you have such information, you see that the Killing form is nondegenerate and, hence, the Lie group is semisimple; the root system has type $B_2$ and, hence, is irreducible. Thus, the group/algebra is simple as well.